# How to get push notification payload of the currently clicked notification in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, firebase, push-notification

I have the below code. My use case is in app terminated state. In terminated state if the app receives only one firebase push notification, tapping on that I am able to get the payload. Using this I navigate to a screen from flutter. But if the app receives multiple push notifications, I am not able to get the payload of the tapped notification. How to fix this? I tried all delegate methods, but none are working. Really need some help.

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging
import os
 
@available(iOS 14.0, *)
@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    let logger = Logger(subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!, category: "push")
    
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        logger.log("flutter - ios didFinishLaunchingWithOptions")
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
        }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        if let notification = launchOptions?[.remoteNotification] as? [String: Any] {
            logger.log("flutter - ios remote notification tapped userinfo \(notification, privacy: .public)")
            if let link = notification["link"] as? String {
                logger.log("flutter - ios link found launch options: \(link, privacy: .public)")
                setFlutterLinkVariable(link)
            } else {
                logger.log("flutter - ios no link found launch options")
            }
        } else if let notification = launchOptions?[.localNotification] as? [String: Any] {
            logger.log("flutter - ios local notification tapped userinfo \(notification, privacy: .public)")
            if let link = notification["link"] as? String {
                logger.log("flutter - ios link found launch options: \(link, privacy: .public)")
                setFlutterLinkVariable(link)
            } else {
                logger.log("flutter - ios no link found launch options")
            }
        }
        
        let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window = window
            
        let flutterViewController = FlutterViewController()
        window.rootViewController = flutterViewController
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
    
    func setFlutterLinkVariable(_ link: String) {
        let controller = window.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
        let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "push_notification_channel", binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
        channel.invokeMethod("setLinkVariable", arguments: link)
    }
    
    func setFlutterLinkClickedVariable() {
        let controller = window.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
        let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "push_notification_channel", binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
        channel.invokeMethod("setLinkClickedVariable", arguments: "true")
    }
    
    func handleNotificationPayload(_ payload: [String: AnyObject]) {
        logger.log("flutter - handleNotificationPayload")
        if let link = payload["link"] as? String {
            logger.log("flutter - push received payload link: \(link)")
            setFlutterLinkVariable(link)
        }
    }
    
    /// App recevied a remote notification
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        logger.log("flutter - ios notification received")
        handleNotificationPayload(userInfo as! [String : AnyObject])
        completionHandler(.newData)
    }

    /// User clicked on a notification
    override func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        logger.log("flutter - ios notification clicked")
        let notificationRequest = response.notification.request
        logger.log("flutter - ios notification clicked userinfo: \(notificationRequest.content.userInfo, privacy: .public)")
        if let userInfo = notificationRequest.content.userInfo as? [String: Any] {
            if let link = userInfo["link"] as? String {
                logger.log("flutter - ios link found UNNotificationResponse: \(link, privacy: .public)")
                setFlutterLinkVariable(link)
            } else {
                logger.log("flutter - ios link not found UNNotificationResponse")
            }
        }
        setFlutterLinkClickedVariable()
    }
    
    override func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        if let link = userInfo["link"] as? String {
            logger.log("flutter - ios link found will present UNNotificationResponse: \(link, privacy: .public)")
            setFlutterLinkVariable(link)
        } else {
            logger.log("flutter - ios link not found in will present UNNotificationResponse")
        }
        completionHandler([.alert, .sound, .badge])
    }
    
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
        print("token: \(deviceToken)")
        super.application(application, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: deviceToken)
    }
}
```

Also the logs are not showing properly in Console app. I am filtering using subcategory using the app identifier. But the sequence of events are not showing properly. So I am not able to debug this properly. Any idea on this is appreciated. Thanks.

---

A scenario I found is that if I receive multiple push, the first tap will give the payload. Then I won't get any payload for other notifications. If I receive a new notification, then I will get the payload for the next tap. After that tap, I don't receive any payload.

---

Simplified code which checks for payload when user taps a notification. But the issue is not fixed.

```
override func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    os_log("notification tapped %{public}@", log: OSLog.push, type: .info, userInfo)
    handleNotificationPayload(userInfo as! [String: AnyObject])
    setFlutterLinkClickedVariable()
}
```

I found that logging is not reliable. Some times it does not event print app did finish launching.